# Как работают сиды

Tags: разработка-игр, случайные-числа, seed

Как можно в нескольких символах записать целую карту от игры? Объясните систему их работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это начальное значение для генератора псевдо-случайных чисел.

Comment: можно пример на javascript

Comment: Здесь есть хороший пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator

Answer (score 2):

Seed - это начальное значение для генератора псевдо-случайных чисел. Имея его, вы получаете одинаковую последовательность (ряд) любого количества случайных чисел. Имея их, вы можете, например:

- скормить первые 10000 в шум Перлина, чтобы создать карту высот местности,
- еще 1000 отдать на выбор типа местности в зависимости от высоты и случайного выбора
- следующие 5000 взять для расстановки и выбора объектов (камни, деревья, и т.п.)
- расставить группы врагов/препятствий/бонусов и т.п. - всё это так же используя числа из ряда

То есть практически все на уровне может быть случайным (в рамках определенных вами правил), а Seed - это число, которое предоставляет вам одинаковую и неограниченную последовательность этих псевдо-случайных чисел.

---

Подробнее о реализации, особенностях и недостатках (которые для игр кстати не критичны) ГПСЧ вы можете почитать на Вики: [Генератор псевдослучайных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)